# Find the function given its entire graph, complete domain, full codomain and exact parts of its graph as other functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I need to find a continuous function with its domain in the closed continuous interval $ [0-\frac{\pi}{2}] $. Its complete range or codomain is within closed continuous interval $ [1-\sqrt2] $.
I also know that from 0 to $ \frac{\pi}{4} $ my function behaves exactly like a $ \frac{1}{\cos(x)} $ function, while beyond $ \frac{\pi}{4} $ till $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ it behaves like a $ \frac{1}{\sin(x)} $ function. Is there such a continuous function?

[image: graph]

Comment: Because I'm very sure I'm missing something here, I expect someone to see a trivial solution and answer like: " Your graph seems to be created by the simple $ \sqrt2\tan(x) $ function" or something of the sorts...

Comment: I don't think it's a cubic cusp or the sorts because I already defined the function in two separate precise trigonometric functions. I want a continuous function giving me the same graph.

Comment: I also don't think interpolation is necessary...or is it? I feel I'm missing something here and that the answer is trivial...

Comment: Hold on, I think I have it. Is it $$ \frac {1}{\cos\biggr(90*int\big(\frac{x}{45}\big)-x\biggr)} $$ ?? I think it is! Oh c**ap! I'm so stupid!

Comment: How stupid can one be to spend an hour on a trivial solution? Answer: A lot!

Comment: What is int?????

Comment: The piecewise continuous function is continuous because both pieces have the same value where they meet.

Comment: INT Function is a function which is responsible for returning the integer portion of a number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_function. Very weird someone of your reputation doesn't know that. It's basic standard notation...

Comment: Maybe I didn't stress enough, nor used the proper terminology or didn't expressed clear enough: I want only one function doing the same graph. I don't want to use 2 separate trig functions on the full domain. I want A SINGLE MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSION doing (or making, or creating, or forming) the same graph. A single mathematical expression. A single function. One.